# Windows not picking up USB devices

Tags: windows, usb

Windows doesn't want any USB devices since last reboot, but Arch sees them.

My laptop (Asus N75SL, almost new) has decided that on windows it did not want to register USB devices. Since the machine dual boots Archlinux (for work purposes) I checked whith him and it registers the Apple keyboard and the gaming mouse no problem. I tried other devices besides mouse and keyboard such as USB headset and DAC.

To be noted that the said devices were registering fine one week before and the keyboard and headset were registering last reboot. The last software to be installed was the RC for Visual Studio 2012 and the update for windows defender.

I'm currently uninstalling VS2012 (to be sure). But I have doubts since it didn't break any other PCs I tried it on.

Comment: When you open up Device Manager, any Yellow Exclamation points standing out?  Anything in the Event Log as far as errors go?

Comment: The todays error are: ESENT Can't open log file and CAPI2 can't init because of ESENT failing (This was during VS2012 uninstall)

Comment: Nope, Just not picking up that the devices are plugged in.

Comment: The USB3 on Asus laptops are not well supported. Try to reconnect to different side of laptop, some of USB ports are still USB2 kind. And to resolve completely, load the drivers from Asus web site.

Comment: @"Rocket Surgeon" Well it was working fine until today

Comment: Have you performed a disk/file system check?  Assuming Windows Vista+, have you tried a Windows [System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) back to a point in time when it WAS working?  What @RocketSurgeon says has truth to it, many of the USB3 ports from the last year or so have some funky firmware problems, did you try other ports?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows root certificates. MS may have security patches or updates for the standard root certificates that are installed in Windows. These are needed to install signed drivers, including drivers for HIDs.

I had a Windows XP machine once that would no longer accept a USB keyboard or mouse, and this was the issue. For some reason, the certificates were gone or never updated, thus expired.